# nginx location regex: unknown "1" variable

Tags: nginx

I wanna make some video downloadable, but my strategy doesn't seem to work...

```
  location ~* ^/(this-video.mp4)(/.*)$ {
    alias /some/path/this-video.mp4;
    add_header Content-Type 'video/mp4';
    if ( $2 = "/dl" ) {
      add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="$1"';
    }
  }
```

Error:

> # nginx -t
>
> nginx: [emerg] unknown "1" variable
>   nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

```
# nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.6.2
```

Any idea what I did it wrong?

***EDIT***:

BTW, this one pass the test:

```
  location ~* ^/(this-video.mp4)(/.*)$ {
    alias /some/path/$1;
    add_header Content-Type 'video/mp4';
    #if ( $2 = "/dl" ) {
    #  add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="$1"';
    #}
  }

# nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

So it must have something to do with quotes?

***EDIT2***

Nginx [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) state:

> A condition may be any of the following:
>
> a variable name; false if the value of a variable is an empty string or “0”;

So if `/dl` is not provided in the url, then `$2` should be an empty string?

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that the numeric captures do not make it through the `if` block, presumably because the `if` condition can also be a new regular expression. You can solve the problem by using named captures instead, for example:

```
location ~* ^/(?<filename>.+\.mp4)(?<suffix>/.*)$ { ... }
```

However, it is [not advisable](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) to use some types of `if` blocks, so you might consider using two location blocks instead:

```
location ~* ^/(.+\.mp4)/dl$ {
    alias /some/path/$1;
    add_header Content-Type 'video/mp4';
    add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="$1"';
}
location ~* ^/(.+\.mp4) {
    alias /some/path/$1;
    add_header Content-Type 'video/mp4';
}
```

Or something simpler for the second location, if applicable, like a prefix location containing a `root` directive.

Comment: This is exactly why I'm not using 2 blocks of `location`, and exactly why I think, that `if` in this particular *location* should do good.